# Playwright redirects instead of opening accordion

Tags: javascript, onclick, automated-tests, puppeteer, playwright

I'm trying to automate the google login process for an app that's not yet verified hence I'm trying to click on the following link:

[image]

Which opens the accordion so:

[image]

I'm doing:

```
await popup.click('[jsname="BO4nrb"]');
```

Google's html is:

```
<a href="#" jsname="BO4nrb" class="xTI6Gf vh6Iad">Advanced</a>
```

Unlike the native browser behaviour when I run the tests (with `--headed`) the accordion doesn't open but instead I'm redirected to https://accounts.google.com/#.

For some reason google's `onclick` javascript is not firing when simulated by playwright and I'm being redirected to `#`

I don't really care to simulate this properly since this is a temporary situation so any hacky solution will also do.

Comment: Is there any page you can share that it would take us there?

Comment: @hardkoded I'm not sure it's safe to share that URL.

Comment: Can you try `page.mouse.click(selector)` instead